# What is a "closed expression" in the context of logic?

Tags: terminology, logic

I was reading about logic systems and the following phrase appeared.

> any **closed expression** that is not derivable inside the same system

What is a "closed expression" in this context? What does "closed expression that is not derivable" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **closed expression** (or **closed formula**) refers to a formula that has no free variables [[1]](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/raut/logic3/announce.pdf#page=79). This is also called **sentence**.

In a logic system, you have a set of axioms, which are sentences, and rules which state how to derive a sentence from this [[2]](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/raut/logic3/announce.pdf#page=55). If a sentence can be derived from the axioms, this means that the axioms [entail](https://cs.calvin.edu/courses/cs/344/kvlinden/resources/AIMA-3rd-edition.pdf#page=259) this sentence. If a sentence is not derivable, it is not entailed by the axioms.